# Матрица выводит столбцы со значением нулей

Tags: c, codeblocks

**Проблема:** Не выводится значение столбцов

**Код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int A[100][100];
    int n,m;
    int i,j;
    printf("Strok :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Stolb :");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;i<m;j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d", *(A+i+j));
        }printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", A[i][j] );
        }printf("\n");
    }
return 0;}
```

**Вывод:**
[image: Вывод]

Почему не выводится значение столбцов?

Comment: `A+i+j` - ??? *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Потому что `scanf("%d", *(A+i+j))` делает не то, что надо. Так будет работать только для одномерных массивов, для двумерных надо `&A[i][j]`

Answer (score 2):

В выводе никаких проблем нет. Все "значения столбцов" выводятся правильно - какие вы дали, такие и выводятся.

Все проблемы - во вводе.

Адресная арифметика для доступа к элементу `[i][j]` двумерного массива `A` через операторы "бинарный `+`" и "унарный `*`" выглядит так

```
*(*(A + i) + j)
```

Соответственно, указатель на элемент можно получить либо как `&*(*(A + i) + j)`, либо, эквивалентно, как `*(A + i) + j`.

Откуда вы взяли ваше `*(A + i + j)` - не ясно.